# How can I transform a String given from keyboard into a Timestamp, and then compare it to a sql Timestamp

Tags: java

I want to transform a String that looks like an sql Timestamp into an actual Timestamp. How can I do that? My string looks like this.

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Please enter StartTime (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS): ");

    String StartTime = null;

    try {
        StartTime = reader.readLine();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then, I want to compare this timestamp, with a Timestamp from an sql database..Can I do something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Timestamp.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) to convert it to a `java.sql.Timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplay use the class `SimpleDateFormat`.According to documentation :

`SimpleDateFormat is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates in a locale-sensitive manner. It allows for formatting (date -> text), parsing (text -> date), and normalization.`